# What is the right place for default gateway in CentOS/RHEL?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, redhat, gateway

As I can see there are 2 places where GATEWAY option could be used in CentOS:

1. /etc/sysconfig/network
2. /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*

What is the right place for default gateway and what the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current convention is `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX`.

That's how Red Hat's tools (e.g. `system-config-network`) are configuring things, and it helps with persistence as NICs change, etc.

Edit:

This depends on how many interfaces you may have. Suppose you have two interfaces, eth0 and eth1, on the same subnet... What if I want the default gateway access to flow through eth0? I'd define it in the interface specification rather than the global `/etc/sysconfig/network` file. Of course, this can also be done in that file using the `GATEWAYDEV` directive...

Comment: Why is that current convention? I have always used "/etc/sysconfig/network". It seems logical, since a host should only have a single default gateway, and not a different one for each interface. That's what route-ethX would be used for.

Comment: See updated answer.